# How to adjust table for a plot? More space for table and graph matplotlib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to separate or increase the distance of my table and my graph so they don't layover. I thought of increasing the size to right and put the table there but I can't seem to make it work, and I can't find a way to offset the table by 1 line.

Graph

[image]

```
global dataread
global top4
global iV
top4mod = [] #holder for table, combines amplitude and frequency (bin*3.90Hz)


plt.plot(x1, fy1, '-') #plot x-y
plt.axis([0, 500, 0, 1.2]) #range for x-y plot
plt.xlabel('Hz')

columns = ('Frequency','Hz')
rows = ['# %d' % p for p in (1,2,3,4)] #top4
colors = 'C0'
print(len(rows))
print(len(str(top4)))
print(top4)


iV=[d*bins for d in iV]  # convert bins into frequency

i=0;
FirstCol = [4, 3, 2, 1]
while i < 4:
    Table.append([iV[i]] + [top4[i]])#[FirstCol[i]]
    i = i+1

cell_text = []
n_rows = len(Table)
index = np.arange(len(columns)) + 1  #0.3 orginal
bar_width = 0.4

y_offset = np.array([0.0] * len(columns))

for row in range(n_rows):
    #plt.bar(index, Table[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color='C0')  #dont use this
    y_offset = y_offset + Table[row]
    cell_text.append(['%1.1f' % p for p in y_offset])

the_table = plt.table(cellText=Table,rowLabels=rows, colLabels=columns,loc='bottom')
#plt.figure(figsize=(7,8))


# Adjust layout to make room for the table:
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2) #left=0.2, bottom=0.2


plt.show() #display plot
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [Tight Layout](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html)?

Comment: @yputons Tables are ignored by `tight_layout()`, so that does not help.

Answer (score 13):

#### Using `bbox`

You can set the position of the table using the `bbox` argument. It expects either a bbox instance or a 4-tuple of values `(left, bottom, width, height)`, which are in axes coordinates. E.g.

```
plt.table(...,  bbox=[0.0,-0.5,1,0.3])
```

produces a table that is as wide as the axes (`left=0, width=1`) but positionned below the axes (`bottom=-0.5, height=0.3`).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(4,2)
columns = ('Frequency','Hz')
rows = ['# %d' % p for p in (1,2,3,4)] 

plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], '-') #plot x-y
plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1.2]) #range for x-y plot
plt.xlabel('Hz')


the_table = plt.table(cellText=data,rowLabels=rows, colLabels=columns,
                      loc='bottom', bbox=[0.0,-0.45,1,.28])
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Create dedicated axes

You can also create an axes (`tabax`) to put the table into. You would then set the `loc` to `"center"`, turn the axis spines off and only use a very small subplots_adjust bottom parameter.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(4,2)
columns = ('Frequency','Hz')
rows = ['# %d' % p for p in (1,2,3,4)] 

fig, (ax, tabax) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

ax.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], '-') #plot x-y
ax.axis([0, 1, 0, 1.2]) #range for x-y plot
ax.set_xlabel('Hz')

tabax.axis("off")
the_table = tabax.table(cellText=data,rowLabels=rows, colLabels=columns,
                      loc='center')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome this worked! Curious though, for the second implementation, it created two Figures (1 & 2). 1 with only drawn graph then another window with Graph and Table. Is there away to only have the Graph & Table window show?

Comment: Both examples are working code and create a single window. So I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: When I changed my code and ran the script, it populated 2 windows. 1 with only a graph and  1 with graph and table. Is it only supposed to populate 1 window?

Comment: To see what it's supposed to do, copy the code from the question **without changing** it. In both cases a single window is shown up. Now, if you change the code, I cannot help you unless you tell me what you have changed.