# Include a summary of text in grided form in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I have a collection of values and labels that I'd like to include as a summary table within a matplotlib plot.

My table looks similar to this:

[image]

I'm currently using the matplotlib.pyplot `text` method applied a previously created axis object (ie, `ax.text()`) to specify locations for each of the entries and labels, but it's incredibly tedious and imprecise.

Imagine there's a more efficient way to do this, but haven't found one despite being somewhat familiar with a few of the data visualization libraries in python (eg, seaborn, plotly etc).

To be clear, the matplotlib `table` method, or answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137396/how-do-i-plot-only-a-table-in-matplotlib), don't address my question.  Looking for an option with cleaner-looking output.

Comment: The picture you show is easily achiveable with `plt.table` shown in the link. So what exactly did you try and where did you get stuck? Or what is this question really about?

Comment: I gather through additional parameters?  Every example I found resulted in a similar basic solid line grid. Looking for something 'clean' in the way of seaborn

Comment: Seaborn does not provide any tables; it's a package for statistical plots built on top of matplotlib. You would also want to decide if you are looking for a matplotlib- or a plotly solution. Then show what you have tried, i.e. at least read through the list of arguments to the table function.

Comment: going through the documentation now, will update shortly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332924/plot-table-alongside-sns-barplot